# Can Oracle create the same tablespace from Instance A on Instance B?

Tags: oracle, configuration, instance, tablespace

Good day. I'm relative new to the Oracle world, we have a client that have 3 Services running and 1 Instance per Service, the problem that we have it's that the client wants to create a tablespace Alpha, which exists for Instance Alpha, in the Instance Beta but also in the Instance Gamma. But when the tablespace creation script is running in the Instance Beta or Gamma returns an error indicating that there is a tablespace with the Alpha name existing, when we review this issue we saw that even if there are multiple instances running there is only one folder that contains all the tablespaces, it is normal to have only one folder that contains all the tablespaces of all instances or it's a bad configuration issue?.

Oracle 11g.
Server: Windows Server 2012.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/physical.htm#i2009)

Comment: Yes i did and as always the Oracle documentation is equals to Microsoft's, which means that is not clear enough, and that's why i made the question, because in the documentation does not refers to the problem that i have.